# How to force script.sh to run as subshell not child?

Tags: bash, subshell

I have several kinds of buildA.sh, buildB.sh, ... scripts which compile some codes.
I also have a general script common.sh which do pre-process, set environments and set trap command.

```
cat common.sh 
~~~
./buildA.sh  #call build.sh, other build.sh run in other directory.
~~~
```

I need to make build.sh run as subshell from common.sh to re-use trap command and non-export variable access to common.sh
Is there any way to do that or workaround?

Comment: I already tried exec buildA.sh, it replace common.sh but trap and variable is disappeared.

Comment: I do not know if this is possible, but if not, a workaround would be to put your trap and variable in a file and source it from your buildX.sh.

Comment: Is this what you wanted : `. ./buildA.sh` ?

Comment: Thanks, your answers could be a somewhat workaround.

Comment: From comments, I reorder the sequence. I modified every script (buildA.sh buildB.sh and...) to run source common.sh. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to `source` the script to run it in the current shell. This is not a subshell, but I think that's what you really want:

```
source build.sh
```

Or the equivalent simple syntax:

```
. build.sh
```

Comment: I think using source is the most acceptable option. I thought there is other way. source would be enough. thanks redseven and Philippe.

Comment: If I use "source", the $LINE and $BASH_SOURCE always return that line "source build.sh" not the real contents.　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
<code>----
    trap 'exitcode=$? LINE=$LINENO                                                 
    echo "[ERROR]: $BASH_SOURCE: $LINE: $BASH_COMMAND: exit $exitcode"
    exit $exitcode                                                       
    'ERR EXIT ... 
-----</code>